# Java(eclipse) scanner

Tags: java, eclipse

if i input 1 then my program uses firstMethod, if i input 2 it uses secondMethod
problem is if i input 3,4 or any other number it doesn't just simply print out input-output error, how could i set range or something like that so anything other than 1 or 2 prints out input-output error ?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner((System.in));
    if (sc.hasNextInt())
        m = sc.nextInt();
    else {
        System.out.println("input-output error");
        sc.close();
        return;         
    }
```

`switch(m){
    case 1:
        firstMethod(a);
        break;
    case 2:
        secondMethod(a);
        break;
    }`

```
 default:
    System.out.println("input-output error");
    break;
```

Comment: use the `default` case.

Comment: `default: System.out.println("input-output error");`

Comment: You will need a default case..go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html Read the official java docs and try out simultaneously

Comment: If you want to do a range of values, you will have to use if else statements. i.e. m>3 && m<6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch has a "default" case:

```
switch(m){
    case 1:
        firstMethod(a);
        break;
    case 2:
        secondMethod(a);
        break;
    default:
         System.out.println("input-output error");
         break;
    }
```

Comment: ussing     dafault: System.out.println("input-output error");
                break;   doesnt work still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `default` in switch statement.

```
switch(m){
    case 1:
        firstMethod(a);
        break;
    case 2:
        secondMethod(a);
        break;
    default:
         System.out.println("input-output error");
         break;
    }
```

The idea of `default` is that if the case is not defined it will run the commands in `default`.

Answer (score -2):

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner((System.in));
  while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
  m = sc.nextInt();

  switch(m) {
    case 1:
      firstMethod(a);
      break;
    case 2:
      secondMethod(b);
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("input-output error");
    }
  }
  sc.close();
```

With this implementation, if `m` is an integer equal to anything other than `1` or `2` (-1, 0, 400,950, etc.), it will go to the  default case which will print out "input-output error".

Note: each `case` is accessed based off what `m` is equal to, so code each `case` based off what you expect `m` to be.

Comment: Does not solve op's problem..also break; is not used in default case

Comment: This EXACTLY solves op's problem, considering the best answer and mine are identical, other than the break.

Comment: Also.. From The C programming language - Second edition (K&R 2, As a matter of good form, put a break after the last case (the default here) even though it's logically unnecessary